# How to calculate close crop rectangle of a bitmap?

Tags: delphi, image-processing

I need to calculate a close crop rectangle for a bitmap by a given background color key. In the following pictures you can see what is meant to be the close crop. On the left side is the source, on the right side output of the close crop:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I need to find the topmost, leftmost, lowermost and rightmost pixels which differ in color from the background to build the close crop rectangle. So, how to find those differing outer pixels to get the close crop rectangle ? Or, in other words, how to calculate close crop rectangle of a bitmap ?

Comment: I have tried a mix of code from some answers David helped me on recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503428/resize-the-canvas-around-a-bitmap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499069/moving-bitmap-pixels I thought I could understand it but not really. I should be able to adapt the ResizeBitmapCanvas procedure to do this but I couldnt, I get confused easily.

Comment: @Blobby one way to do it is to start from each side of the bitmap and decrement the loop variable until you find a pixel that is different from the background color, repeat process for each side and voila, you got yourself a auto cropping tool

Comment: @Dorin, you can do it in one `ScanLine` pass trough, you just have to remember the limits ;-)

Comment: @TLama I'm not sure about that, the cube for example could have the right "edge" inclined(not straight) so, you end up with pretty bad cropping, it could be that I'm missing somethign tho' (:

Comment: @Dorin, no, you just have to remember the last right *dirty* pixel position in that case. You will scan from top to bottom and when you find a *dirty* one which is more far from left then you store that one's position etc.

Comment: @TLama oh, my bad, it's a "normal" crop, not a crop around the shape(s)

Comment: I think I understand the basic principle of scanline (iterate each pixel in a row rather than one individual pixel at a time?) but then after that I have no real idea. The way it should work is by finding the first nearest top/left pixel, then bottom/left, top/right, bottom/right etc and crop from that leaving a 1 pixel border. The images should demonstrate that better then me trying to explain.

Comment: @DorinDuminica what if the background color was not solid, eg a gradient how would that be able to work using your loop suggestion?

Comment: @Blobby if the background is not one color, then it doesn't qualify for the current question (: but anyhu, you can calculate color intensity and do other tricks, your images in question have the same background color

Comment: @DorinDuminica that is fine I wasn't looking to change the question. I just did not think that would be a method to finding where to crop, I was just speculating as to how it could work if the background was not solid :)

Comment: I've radically modified your question and removed that extra 1 pixel around the output close crop rectangle requirement as it's easy to modify the output rectangle that way. If you don't like it, rollback to the previous revision, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this code (you may follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10533819/4) of this post as well):

```
procedure CalcCloseCrop(ABitmap: TBitmap; const ABackColor: TColor;
  out ACropRect: TRect);
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Color: TColor;
  Pixel: PRGBTriple;
  RowClean: Boolean;
  LastClean: Boolean;
begin
  if ABitmap.PixelFormat <> pf24bit then
    raise Exception.Create('Incorrect bit depth, bitmap must be 24-bit!');

  LastClean := False;
  ACropRect := Rect(ABitmap.Width, ABitmap.Height, 0, 0);

  for Y := 0 to ABitmap.Height-1 do
  begin
    RowClean := True;
    Pixel := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      Color := RGB(Pixel.rgbtRed, Pixel.rgbtGreen, Pixel.rgbtBlue);
      if Color <> ABackColor then
      begin
        RowClean := False;
        if X < ACropRect.Left then
          ACropRect.Left := X;
        if X + 1 > ACropRect.Right then
          ACropRect.Right := X + 1;
      end;
      Inc(Pixel);
    end;

    if not RowClean then
    begin
      if not LastClean then
      begin
        LastClean := True;
        ACropRect.Top := Y;
      end;
      if Y + 1 > ACropRect.Bottom then
        ACropRect.Bottom := Y + 1;
    end;
  end;

  if ACropRect.IsEmpty then
  begin
    if ACropRect.Left = ABitmap.Width then
      ACropRect.Left := 0;
    if ACropRect.Top = ABitmap.Height then
      ACropRect.Top := 0;
    if ACropRect.Right = 0 then
      ACropRect.Right := ABitmap.Width;
    if ACropRect.Bottom = 0 then
      ACropRect.Bottom := ABitmap.Height;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  CalcCloseCrop(Image1.Picture.Bitmap, $00FFA749, R);
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SetSize(R.Width, R.Height);
    Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, R.Width, R.Height), Image1.Canvas, R);
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent stuff TLama, no taking credit away from this one ;) I just wish I could understand not just your answer, but many others. EDIT: the pixels on a bitmap, are they surrounded by an invisible box (bounding box) as I thought originally? If so is this found by using Rect?

Comment: I'll try to comment this, but after a review. About the invisible box, do you mean some empty space around the cropped image, right ? I'll add some, but what if the first (non-background) pixel will be on position [0;0], do you want to extend it behind the image size and fill this outer space with ABackColor ?

Comment: @TLama see the question, I edited it to try and show what exactly I meant by invisible bounding box (is there even such a thing??). I think if the first pixel is [0,0] then no cropping would occur.

Comment: I see, so just an extra empty space around the crop result. About the first top left pixel case, you're right, there won't be any crop, but do you want to extend the image with that space even in this case ? Still, the easiest way to this is to get the tight crop rectangle (with the CalcCloseCrop), create a temporary bitmap with the size of ACropRect + the bounding space, fill it with ABackColor and copy the area of ACropRect from the source image to the center of that temporary bitmap. And make from that temporary bitmap result :-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, regardless if there is a top left pixel or not an extra space around the crop could be made.

Comment: Why is `Pixel` variable declared as PRGBTriple? Does that return the `Color` value for the found pixels?

Comment: Try to take a look at [`this article`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29173). The result of the `ScanLine` function is a pointer to the first color structure representing the first pixel of the line. This structure consists from the count of byte values used for representing one single pixel. If you have 24-bit image, you will use PRGBTriple (pointer to TRGBTriple record with 3 bytes inside), because the 24-bit image pixel is stored as 3 bytes like Blue-Green-Red. If you would have 8-bit image, you will use only PByte (pointer to a single byte). The `Inc(Pixel);` from this example means..

Comment: ..that you increment the pointer value by size of one pixel structure, so you are going to point to the next pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the article link it will help me at least understand some of what is going on.