# How to get mouse cursor dimensions on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mouse, hint

I use `Toolbar2000` component. It shows button's hint below correct position with system scale > 100%. So, I need to set HintPos manually. I have `Mouse.CursorPos`. But hint should be displayed below mouse cursor image.

How to get mouse cursor dimensions?

Comment: maybe this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648387(v=vs.85).aspx is what you're looking for?

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo your link claims: "The structure receives the dimensions of the screen if the cursor is not confined to a rectangle" - do you really think that the whole desktop may be the size of the cursor ? That is a very different thing - that si a windows which cursor cannot move outside of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Windows 7 issue and there is no proper solution. `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)` returns size of cursor image with background. And it seems this value is much more incorrect with system scale >100%. Delphi XE2 shows a hint on incorrect position too. But it's interesting to note that Explorer shows a hint on the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask Windows for `System Metrics` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385.aspx

However if user installed something like Stardock CursorFX those values would not match what the user really sees and what behavior he expects from programs.

That seems to be one of Win32 API limitations, that the value cannot be changed apart of few relatively small standard values from old approved set.

Comment: No, you can use [`such code`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/20/10078140.aspx).

Comment: @TLama it would still not account for 3rd-party Windows extensions. Also think that the cursor may change every second, due to any Windows event like inserting new disk or whatever. So if you would go pixel-hunting, would you repeat it 20 times per second to move hint windows aftewr the shape of the cursor changed?

Comment: What are you talking about ? We're talking about cursors, not about 3rd party something. You should at least mention `SM_CXCURSOR` and `SM_CYCURSOR` constants you should ask for, not only *ask something behind the external link which might get invalid this year*. Not voting down, but your answers sometimes deserve it. I have nothing more to say...

Comment: The link is to official documentation. SO should not become a replacement for it. SO links can go down, be incorrect, be edited to become incorrect, its. MSDN is a primary data source on this question. Also i cannot understand why link to an unofficial blog with hackerish code is good, and the link to official documentation is bad. That does not look consistent.

Comment: I have tried this approach but `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)` has a value in 5-10 times more than correct size (with system scale 200% on Retina display).

Comment: Maybe LOGPIXEL may help but i don't think it is proper solution then. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877.aspx

Comment: In Win7 there is "use WinXP scaling" checkbox in Fonts DPI dialog. Maybe it affects the metrics...

Comment: I think `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)` returns a size of a cursor's background - not of a cursor.

Comment: the cursor is a picture - the picture that has transparent pixels just like an item. it may have all pixels transparent or all pixels opaque, but usually, just like with icons, it is a mix of both. System Metrics is a size of that picture, but which pixels in is are transparent or not - that System Metrics cannot know. Afterall the cursor may change several times per second

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Icon, use `GetCursor` to set the handle, additional information can be retrieved with `GetIconInfo`. This will even work if userdefined cursors are shown, which might have nearly any size.

```
var
  ico: TIcon;
  IcoInfo: TIconInfo;
begin
  ico := TIcon.Create;
  try
    ico.Handle := GetCursor;
    try
      GetIconInfo(ico.Handle, IcoInfo);
      Caption := Format('Width %d, Height %d HotSpotX %d, HotSpotY %d',
        [ico.Width, ico.Height, IcoInfo.xHotspot, IcoInfo.yHotspot]);
    finally
      ico.ReleaseHandle;
    end;
  finally
    ico.Free;
  end;
end;


// Just as example for an very unusual cursor
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  AndMask, Bmp: TBitmap;
  w, h: Integer;
begin
  w := Screen.Width * 2;
  h := Screen.Height * 2;

  // Creation And Mask
  AndMask := TBitmap.Create;
  AndMask.Monochrome := True;
  AndMask.Height := h;
  AndMask.Width := w;

  // Draw on And Mask
  AndMask.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.FillRect(AndMask.Canvas.ClipRect);

  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Color := clwhite;
  AndMask.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(w div 2, 0);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w div 2, h);
  AndMask.Canvas.MoveTo(0, h div 2);
  AndMask.Canvas.LineTo(w, h div 2);

  {Create the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;

  Bmp.Width := w;
  Bmp.Height := h;

  {Draw on the "XOr" mask}
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clblack;
  Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, w, h));
  Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := clwhite;
  Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
  Bmp.Canvas.MoveTo(w div 2, 0);
  Bmp.Canvas.LineTo(w div 2, h);
  Bmp.Canvas.MoveTo(0, h div 2);
  Bmp.Canvas.LineTo(w, h div 2);


  IconInfo.fIcon := true;
  IconInfo.xHotspot := w div 2;
  IconInfo.yHotspot := h div 2;
  IconInfo.hbmMask := AndMask.Handle;
  IconInfo.hbmColor :=  Bmp.Handle;

  Screen.Cursors[1]:= CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);
  Screen.Cursor:=1;

end;
```

Comment: The problem with pixel-hunting (including adjusting for HotSpot) is that mouse cursor is intended to change at any second dew to internal or external events...

Comment: My focus was not on hotspot, though it might be interesting with exotic user designed Cursors, such as hintcursors. I just wanted to show one way how to get the needed data.

Comment: Does the upper code give an icon with large transparent background and cursor point at (xHotspot, yHotspot) position? Is there any simple way to calculate its height (except transparent background)?

Comment: `ico.Height` returns the same incorrect value as `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)`. I think it's a size of a cursor's background - not of a cursor.

Comment: @Altaveron retrieving this information would need to step through the scanlines of a bitmap e.g. with icon(cursor) drawn on or generated from IcoInfo.hbmMask/hbmColor.

Comment: @Altaveron, for a close crop rectangle calculation you may take a look e.g. at [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10532445/960757). But you'd need to combine the cursor image with its mask. `</self-promotion>` :-)